# How to create a specific Web App with WordPress?

Tags: third-party-applications

Can we make Web Apps in WordPress with specific (custom) scope, something like a mini-Facebook, a mini-Twitter, a stackoverflow, etc. What I really want to know is that how much am I free handed to build whatever Web App I want in WP? and more importantly how to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course you can make any type of web app.

Use **Page Templates** for different pages, **Custom Post Types** for different data handlers, **Taxonomies** for categorizing those data, and **Plugins** for advanced functionality.

WP Codex is best way to dive into WordPress.

Comment: Is it sufficient to go just with WP Codex?

Comment: @MustafaEhsan You can go with the Codex but just looking up WordPress tutorials and starting from there (be it youtube videos or text guides) just to get a basic understanding of how WordPres templating works and go from there.